# how can i do mining on vmware machine

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-hardware, mining-setup, guiminer

I am new to bitcoin mining.

i have gui-miner, setup a slash mining account, and i have a VM Ware machine setup for mining.

i have my own reasons for using a VM Machine and not my own...

now whenever i open guiminer and click on start mining(given all valid fields and having setup mining worker as well), the miner says that nothing to mine on, exiting.

i do not have any OpenCL or any graphics card as it is a VM Machine.

can anyone help me on this...

Comment: It is very unlikely you will make anything else than a loss mining bitcoin on a computer. GPUs are already pointless, let alone CPUs.

Comment: lolz...its out of curiosity rather than profit...after test environment...i can move to something more productive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, all mining software have GPU and CPU mining disabled by default. You're going to need to recompile from source and enable CPU/GPU mining to be able to mine with your CPU/GPU. You should be warned that this is not profitable in any way, shape, or form and that even on testnet, your CPU won't likely find a block for many hours.

That said, if you're determined to do it, get the source for bfgminer here: https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer

Compile with the `--enable-cpumining` flag and you should have a binary that lets you use the CPU.

Comment: do u have the complete command set and prerequisites for compiling...i am new to this open source compiling thing...:P

Comment: ps i have windows VM system...do i need a linux VM..?/

Comment: The instructions are here: https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/windows-build.txt This is not going to be simple on windows. It's easier on linux but you still need to know what you're doing.